# Using common CSS across all modules, Angular 2 RC6

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I am willing to use a common css, i.e my root css across all modules of app. This can be achieved by adding css path to `styleUrls` tag in all components individually. Is there any other way, like including css at NgModule level?

Comment: why not adding it in your index.html header this should work

Comment: I want to have it module wise, the app is quite big and each module has its own common design elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the styles to the `index.html` page, they are applied to all components, but view encapsulation emulation is not applied.

Besides that I don't think Angular2 itself provides anything.

Comment: What if I want to have module wise common css?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is nothing that Angular2 provides. Perhaps some build tool can add the styles to `styleUrls` of your components (not my area of expertise).

Comment: What about using preprocessors like SASS and imports?

Comment: Haven't tried with SASS yet, its plain vanilla css.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering the same today. There is no functionality for module-wise CSS, so I ended up using Sass imports to achieve what I needed to do.

Please note that although it is repetitive, it is better than having an app-wide CSS, which beats the purpose of encapsulation.

Given the following file structure:

```
my-component/
 ├──first/
 │   ├──first.component.ts     * first component
 │   ├──first.component.scss   * first component's SCSS
 │   └──...                    * first component's module, html etc.
 │
 ├──second/
 │   ├──second.component.ts    * second component
 │   ├──second.component.scss  * second component's SCSS
 │   └──...                    * second component's module, html etc.
 │
 ├──my-component.module.ts     * my component's module 
 ├──my-component.routes.ts     * my component's routes 
 └──_shared.scss               * the shared partial SCSS
```

I import the `_shared` partial into my `first.component.scss` and `second.component.scss`, like so:

```
@import '../shared';
```